# Does FCM resend notifications within a lifetime to new android users?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase for sending notifications to an app users with 4 weeks lifetime. I guess no, but if a new user installs the app, will he recive the alive notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM sends the message *as soon as feasible*. The default `time_to_live` is four weeks, which works in a way that only if the message is that is sent to the corresponding recipients at the time the message was sent, it would only be kept on queue by the FCM servers until such time that they come online.

With your use-case, I'm presuming that this is for Topics Messaging, in which case at the time that the message was *technically sent*, new subscribers will *not* receive it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the time_to_live parameter will affect the delivery of the messages.

This means that the recipient already exists but for some reason the message can't be delivered, and the parameter will be used to set a maximum time of delivery after which FCM will just not go ahead with completing the task.

New users wouldn't qualify as recipients at the time of the message being sent.

[FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)